# Classe para escrever/ler arquivos TXT com formatação

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou utilizando a `Classe` **TextWriter** para ler/escrever um comprovante de cartão em `.txt` porém a mesma não tem a propriedade de formatação de tamanho de letras, espaçamento, etc.
Assim faz o comprovante impresso na impressora térmica sair sem simetria.

Minha pergunta é, existe outra Classe no C# que faz esse processo, porém com as opções de formatação?

```
public void LerConfirmacao()
    {
        if (File.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Comprovante"]))
        {
            File.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Comprovante"]).Close();
        }

        TextWriter textWriter = File.AppendText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Comprovante"]);
        string[] linhas = File.ReadAllLines(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["001Resp"]);
        foreach (string linha in linhas)
        {
            if (linha.Substring(0, 3) == "029")
            {
                textWriter.WriteLine(linha.Substring(10));
            }
        }

        textWriter.Close();

        if (Directory.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pagamentos"]))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pagamentos"]);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pagamentos"]);
        //File.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pagamentos"]).Close();
        string nomeArquivo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pagamentos"] + "Comprovante_" + PedNumero + "_" + PedFrmPgto;
        TextWriter writer = File.AppendText(nomeArquivo);

        foreach (string item in File.ReadAllLines(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Comprovante"]))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(item);
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Não existe formação em arquivos de texto simples.

Comment: @LINQ existe alguma saída? Alteração de procedimento ... (?)

Comment: Usar uma fonte monoespaçada para imprimir (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arquivos .txt não tem formatação. Você deverá usar outra extensão (Exemplo: .rtf).
O que você pode fazer, é usar um `RichTextBox` para formatar o texto.
Exemplo:

```
RichTextBox formatar = new RichTextBox();
formatar.Text = "texto1 ABC";
formatar.Select(2,4);
formatar.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
formatar.SaveFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/teste.rtf");
```